# How to pre-load all tabs by default in Kendo UI TabStrip

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using TabsStrip control from Kendo UI.

I have two dynamic tabs. For the moment, only the first tab is automatically loaded, the second one is loaded when clicked. I want them both to be loaded so that when I click the second one, the content is already loaded.

I didn't find any api way to do that.

Comment: Can you post the code you're working with?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the **[reload](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/tabstrip#reload)** method of the TabStrip when the page is loaded

```
var lastItem = $('#tabstrip .k-item:last');//load just the last
$('#tabstrip').data().kendoTabStrip.reload(lastItem);
```

Or you can loop through all the $('#tabstrip .k-item') items and load them if you need to load all of them initially.